# UIView on top of PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, parse-platform, tableview, pfquery

I'm trying to add a `UIView` on the top bar of a `PFQueryTableView` Controller that's been subclassed via storyboard. I want to add a Cancel button to a custom `UIView` so that it's accessible to the user like a regular top (nav) bar button. Is what I'm trying to do possible or does the fact that it's a `PFQueryTableViewController` make things nasty? I've tried to create a `UIView` programmatically but it does not appear.

And I've messed with the .frame and .center to position it to the top of the viewcontroller. I'm not sure if it's appearing or not.

EDIT: This is essentially what I want to do. **Take a UIView. Put a background color on it. And then position it above or below the PFQueryTableView. Basically my question is, can I add subviews to a PFQuerytableviewController?** Apologies for the vagueness and the reiterations--I'm trying to solve this problem based on how it's been described to me by another developer. .

Comment: This is entirely do-able. But lets get through it 1 step at a time, I think there's several issues at heart here. For the first part, post your code on how you tried to create your UIView

Comment: What's the top bar?  PFQueryTableVC is a subclass of UITableVC.  @Aggressor, adding to its view hierarchy is almost the opposite of entirely doable.  The top bar could be a navigation bar, but that, too has an opaque view hierarchy.

Comment: Theres several issues here with the structure of his question, if we work through all of them I'm confident the problem can be fixed.

Comment: Do you want to add a button to a PFQueryTableViewController that is in a UINavigationView?

Comment: Essentially. However, this button needs to appear in a custom view that I'm building. That view appears on TOP of the PFQueryTableViewController. I've edited the above.

Comment: @danh top bar is the navigation bar.

Comment: @KacheFlowe, navigation bar provides no opportunity to add subviews except those outlined in the api (like bar button items).  Maybe post a more detailed description of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @danH Edited it above. Looks like my fellow dev did not want to actually add it on top of the nav bar. He wanted it above the tableview. Please look at the edit above. Note that I have no implemented any code to achieve the above.